# Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1 Rendering Problems

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-2.2

I'm trying out the new Android Studio 2.2 Preview, and for some reason the layout editor isn't working for layouts that were created in the old version. It keeps telling me various resources aren't found... (Such at the file that I just opened.)

Am I missing something? Is there soemthing I'm unaware of that I should have done when opening an old project?

It seems to be fine when I create a new layout. It's only the previously created layouts and menus that seem to have an issue.

Anyone else experiencing this?

I've tried cleaning, and rebuilding the project.

EDIT

Ok interesting- the problem seems to only happen for layouts that include other layouts. If I remove the include statement it renders fine, but if I add it back, it can't find the included item and gives me an issue. (Even though I can apparently open the included layout itself, and it renders just fine...)

UPDATE

Apparently it only seems to happen with the merge tag. If the layout being included uses the merge tag it won't render and I get the below error. If I remove the merge, and just use another layout tag it seems to work fine.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not find layout resource matching value 0x7FFF03A2 (resolved name: item_monster_edit) in current configuration.
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:913)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:900)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getLayout(Resources_Delegate.java:437)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1111)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:136)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:902)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:854)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:317)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:534)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:534)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$41(RenderTask.java:660)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:380)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.inflate(RenderTask.java:660)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.inflate(NlModel.java:321)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.render(NlModel.java:378)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.DesignSurface$3.modelChanged(DesignSurface.java:794)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.lambda$notifyListenersModelUpdateComplete$52(NlModel.java:454)
at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.notifyListenersModelUpdateComplete(NlModel.java:454)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.updateModel(NlModel.java:368)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel$1.run(NlModel.java:231)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:333)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:323)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:267)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:282)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:378)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.run(Alarm.java:389)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.SchedulingWrapper$MyScheduledFutureTask.run(SchedulingWrapper.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:187)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It's not... It's a different exception being raised. I tried what they suggested - changing back to 23 (it was actually one of the first things I tried) but it didn't work either.

Comment: You have probably messed up something

Comment: Facing the same issue, for me include tag is having issues, commenting the tag renders the UI and uncomment displays the error similar to yours. Seems to be a bug, hopefully will be fixed in next build.

Answer (score 3):

You probably solved this already but I had the same problem with the same error. Always with included layouts.

The solution was to invalidate cache /restart in Android studio. Now it is working and the preview shows the layout with the included layout.

Comment: had the exact same issue with layouts inserted using `include` tag. Solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Press Ctrl+Shift+A (Cmd+Shift+A on Mac?)
Write "invalidate"

Select "Invalidate Caches / Restart"

Comment: I don't think including the keyboard shortcut is enough to differentiate this from the top answer suggesting the same thing.

Comment: Well if i doesn't know where to find Invalidate Caches thing ? it help those.

Answer (score 1):

Seems many developers been experiencing this issue. You can star it here [211183](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211183)

If you cant wait for Tools guys to fix it, switch to older Studio versions. 2.1 should work fine.

Edit: Fixed in Preview 5

Answer (score 0):

Just remove these lines and may b it will get fixed

```
android:background="?android:attr/windowTitleStyle">
```

This happens wen u the attributes arent set properly.